# Different \chi symbols in LaTeX

Tags: latex, xelatex

I am typesetting a LaTeX document with some Greek symbols, using the xelatex engine.

For some reason, the \chi command creates a different symbol than I would expect:

[image: this symbol] versus [image: this other one]

They are close, but  not exactly the same, and I would like to obtain the second.

Is there a special package that I should invoke?

Thanks in advance for any hint,
Adrian

Comment: You are using a non-standard font.  The right one is the default LaTeX font called Computer Modern, the left one is something else which comes from you loading some font package (probably `txfonts` or `mathptmx`).

Comment: Thanks, that was the answer indeed. I am actually using the Computer Modern font using package lmodern, but after that, in the header, I am using package mathptmx which is the culprit. Should you post as an answer, I will mark as complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove any font changing packages from the preamble.

In this case it turned out that the offending one was `mathptmx`.

Comment: This is the correct answer, with minor comment: I managed to get the right font while still preserving `mathptmx`. The trick is to invoke that package *before* package `lmodern` which provides the Computer Modern font. The order of the packages matters, it seems.